# Barabasi-Albert random graph: a proof of the power law considering $t$ continuous.

Tags: probability, random-graphs

**The model:**
We consider the [Barabási–Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model)

**The result I want to show:**
for that model, show that the degree distribution follows a power law with exponent $=3$.

I read this [proof (page 2)](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rav/ComplexNetworks/ComplexNetworks.Lecture12.Notes.pdf) and [this one from the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9910332.pdf%3Forigin%3Dpublication_detail) which are the same. But I don't understand:

- Why can we consider $t$ as continuous? (how to show that it's legit).
- Why can you use the derivative and why $\dfrac{d}{dt}(d_i(t))= \dfrac{d_i(t)}{\sum d_i(t)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, well, because, all the "proofs" you refer to are not rigorous mathematical proofs. Moreover even the statement of the model is ambiguous: they start with a network of $m$ nodes without even specifying what exactly this network is.

So here are two ways to proceed: Accept this kind of reasoning and train your intuition (very often supported by numerical evidence) to become a physicist. Or read the careful mathematical proof, which can be found, e.g., in Random Graphs and Complex Networks: Volume 1 by Remco van der Hofstad ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/110717287X) but pdf should be easy to find). Remember, however, that the actual proof takes a little more than two pages.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! 
Btw, this book can be found for free (and legally!) on the internet (http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.html).
And thank you for this joke about physicist! I laughed a lot!

Comment: @MiKiDe This book is a part of lecture notes that existed for quite a while on the Internet. It is very good that Remco van der Hofstad still keep them available. About physicist it was not a joke. The truth is that most of the facts we know nowadays about complex networks and especially dynamical processes on them were derived with a "physical" level of rigor by people like Barabasi, Mark Newman, and many other. Your can read more about the interplay of obtaining results and proving them in the preface of a (much more demanding) book by Rick Durrett.